# Post inside controller not loading into model in Yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-extensions, yii-form

When I want to get the variable from the form the post action doesn't load  .

This is my view:

```
<?php
        $form = ActiveForm::begin();
        ?>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="FullName">

                <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Start'), ['start', 'link' => $model->link], ['type' => 'button','class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-round']) ?>
            </div>

            <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

This is my controller:

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
    exit(var_dump('everything is ok'));
}else {
    exit(var_dump('nothing is right'));

}
```

The result is 'nothing is right'.

Comment: I think this is because you don't submit the form but you call a normal link. Take a look to Html::submitButton

Comment: I tried but I still get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find the solution

```
<?php
$form = ActiveForm::begin(
    [
        'action' => 'start',
    ]
);
?>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="FullName">
    <?= Html::a('submit', Url::to(['start', 'link' => $model->link]), ['data-method' => 'POST']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end();?>
```

thank you for all

Comment: I change `['start', 'link' => $model->link]` by `Url::to(['start', 'link' => $model->link]` 
 in the form and the code works correctly.

Comment: both are same in case of anchore tag

Comment: so maybe the option `[' data-method '=>' POST '] ` solved the problem

Comment: ok, but your question and answer doesn't match. Please correct the question

Answer (score 1):

Apart from using the anchor link instead of a submit button, you are not using model to create active input hence the field names are without model names or the standard array format that Yii accepts, you should pass empty string to the load method as second parameter which is `formName` like below

```
$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post(),'');
```

So your complete form should look like

```
<?php
    $form = ActiveForm::begin(
        [
            'action' => 'start',
        ]
    );
?>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="FullName">
    <?php echo Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Start'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-round']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end();?>
```

**EDIT**

and your controller code should look like below, mind the first check it needs to be there so that the code is run when you submit only not on page load

```
if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) { //this should be here before the rest of the code

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post(), '')) {
        exit(var_dump('everything is ok'));
    } else {
        exit(var_dump('nothing is right'));
    }

}
```

Comment: this solution does not work for me, the post is still not loaded and the var_dump message is 'nothing is right'

Comment: @adnenmanssouri have you checked what is in the `$model->errors` when it goes in the else part ?

Comment: add the complete code for your controller action @adnenmanssouri and see the edit part and update your code accordingly

Answer (score 0):

This is because `load()` method looks for post data inside model name property and you are writing the input yourself instead of using the Yii method for forms.

So your post `Yii::$app->request->post()` returns:

```
array(
 'username' => 'value of username',
)
```

And your `$model->load` looks for

```
 array(
     'modelName' => array(
         'username' => 'value of username',
       )
  )
```

To make your post data too look like that you could do it the right way that is, delete your Input and use this method inside the form:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
```

Or the wrong way, modify your input and inside username use:

```
<input type="text" name="modelName[username]" placeholder="FullName">
```

Of course where I put username you must put your real model name.

Comment: In this case I'm not using the model but I just want to read the variable sent from the view

Comment: Then don't use `model->load()`. Use `$params = Yii::$app->request->post()` and inside $params you will have $params['username']. Or you could replace `if($model->load(...` with if(Yii::$app->request->post('username')){...}`

Comment: @adnenmanssouri change your `Html::a` for `Html::submitButton`.

Comment: @adnenmanssouri instead of load etc.. do `if(Yii::$app->request->isPost){ var_dump("Hei"); die() } `

Comment: @adnenmanssouri then there you have the problem, inspect the html with F12 in chrome and check what url is inside form action.

Comment: I think the URL is true because the 'var_dump' in the controller works correctly and displays the false case